# What exactly does shift operation whose right operand is over 31 do, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that operands of bitwise operation are treated as 32-bit integers in Javascript. So I thought that it would be zero'd out if I do `<< 32` on integer values. But it worked as if it's `<< 0`. For what reason is it worked in that way? What exactly does shift operation whose right operand is over 31 do, in Javascript?

```
0b00000000000000000000000000000001 << 32 // 1
0b00000000000000000000000000000001 << 33 // 2
0b00000000000000000000000000000001 << 34 // 4

0b00000000000000000000000000000001 >> 30 // 0
0b00000000000000000000000000000001 >> 31 // 0
// Something weird is happening.......
0b00000000000000000000000000000001 >> 32 // 1
0b00000000000000000000000000000001 >> 33 // 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It truncates the binary representation of the right operand.**

From the documentation for [Bitwise Shift Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators):

> Shift operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers in
>   big-endian order and return a result of the same type as the left
>   operand. **The right operand should be less than 32, but if not only the
>   low five bits will be used.**

So in your example, `32` is `0b100000`. Since it only takes the lowest five bits you're left with `0b00000`, so it shifts the number by `0`. Again, `33` is `0b100001` and the lowest five bits are `0b00001`, so it shifts the number by `1`. And so on.

Comment: “The right operand should be less than 32, but if not, only the lowest five bits will be used.” -- Got it; thank you!